# C# Control at Mouse Location Outside of the Application

Tags: c#, .net, dialog

Is it possible to get a control at the current mouse location if its in a window not known by the application? (not in `Application.OpenForms`)

I implemented a low level mouse hook which can get the mouse location anywhere on the screen, but I can't seem to access controls outside of my application.  What I want to be able to do is get a button in an OpenFileDialog.  I can get a Handle to the dialog, but I can't get the control from the dialog using `Control.FromHandle()` since this only works for controls that are in the Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with the Win32 API.  You need GetDlgItem() to get a handle to button you are looking for.  Use Spy++ to find the control ID.  An example of the kind of code you need is available in my post in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/2f17ab18-fb11-401f-bbf6-56faaca95753/).  That example is for an in-process dialog, it would work out-of-process as well.

Beware that your code is liable to break on the next version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get a .NET `Control`, this is not possible. The reason for this is that the `Control` **IS** the [`HWND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632595%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). With `"HWND"` here I mean the actual Windows window item. It is not possible to e.g. automatically wrap a new control instance around an existing window, much less as it's possible to get the `Control` instance from the other .NET application, if it were one.

If you are trying to insert a .NET `Control` into an `OpenFileDialog`, this also will not be possible because the `OpenFileDialog` is not a .NET form.

If you really want the `HWND` from the mouse location, you can use pinvoke to get it using the [`WindowFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function.